# STM32 Freezing periphirals when pausing the debugger

Tags: debugging, gdb, arm, stm32

Debugger can stop execution of code in Cortex when it reaches a breakpoint or user pauses the execurion of code. But does debugger freeze other periphirals like DMA, UART and TIMERS when cortex stops execuring the code in pause state?

Comment: Based on this brief sentence "When the 
program reaches a breakpoint, internal peripherals like 
timers can be frozen in their current state or can be left 
running." from this [doc](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/training/technical/product_training/16/31/0e/0d/94/11/4f/5e/STM32L4_System_Debug.pdf/files/STM32L4_System_Debug.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.STM32L4_System_Debug.pdf), so it depends. I do not know where can you tell the debugger to froze certain peripherals.

Comment: Lookup the DGBMCU on here or google. On the STM32 you can generally have a choice if you want to stop a peripheral when the debugger stops. I found plenty of examples after a quick search. The STM HAL provides an interface if you need code examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only hold time/r depend peripherals.

I call the following code on entering the main function:

```
  DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM2_STOP | DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM3_STOP | 
                    DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM4_STOP | DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM5_STOP);

  DBGMCU->APB2FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB2_FZ_DBG_TIM19_STOP);
```

This stops several timers if your code hit a breakpoint. If your DMA transactions depends on the specified timer (like mine) it will also implicitly stop otherwise not.