# STM32H7 SPI frozen during break?

Tags: stm32, spi

In order to freeze a timer during a break in debug mode on a STM32H7, one has to set a bit in the DBGMCU. But I didn't find such a bit for SPI. Does it mean that the SPI is always frozen ? Or on the contrary never frozen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

There is no such option for the SPI. SPI is always enabled, if used and proper configured.

**Long answer:**

There is no such option for SPI because this interface must be either actively served by the microcontroller. In this case the SPI transaction is automaticly stoped if your device is halted e.g in break mode. Any ongoing transaction of a word/fifo will be executed anyway.

Or the dma controler is configured to server the SPI. In this case data transmission is controlled by the dma controller. The dma controller itself has different trigger sources. As long this trigger source is not a timer depended one there is no way to implicitly halt the transfer.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43225545/5388805